# Limit of $\dfrac{x}{\log x}$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

What would be the value of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x}{\log x}$? Is it infinity or some constant value?

Comment: It is infinity.

Comment: Infinity, but why? You can use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Because $x\gg\log x$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

Comment: @GammaFunction Thanks. I meant that $x\in \Omega(\log x)$

Answer (score 7):

L'Hopital's rule gives answers but not insight.

Look at this:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \log_2 x \\
\hline
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 \\
4 & 2 \\
8 & 3 \\
16 & 4 \\
32 & 5 \\
64 & 6 \\
128 & 7 \\
256 & 8 \\
512 & 9
\end{array}
$$
As $x\to\infty$, what happens to the ratio of the number in the left column to the number in the right column?  That's the answer to the question you posed.

(A moment's thought should tell you why the answer will be the same if the base of the logarithms is any number besides $2$, as long as it's $>1$.)

Answer (score 6):

By L'Hospital's Rule, we have that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}$ $x \over \log(x)$ =$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}$ $1 \over {1/x}$ = $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x$ = $\infty$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule gives answers but not insight.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the change of variables $x=e^y$, here we can consider:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{\ln x}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^y}{\ln e^y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^y}{y}=\infty$$

Comment: And how do you justify the last limit?

Comment: @lhf
by the fact that exponential is much larger than polynmial, but to put forth more rigour:

$\large\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{e^y}{y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1+y+y^2/2!+y^3/3!+...}{y}$

$=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{y}+1+y/2!+y^2/3!+...=\infty$

Comment: In order to avoid complications with infinite sums, you could use the weaker result $e^{y} > 1+y+y^{2}/2$.

Comment: @madprob: It is useful!